# html doesn't update consistently on ref value change in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to display the readyState of a WebSocket connection. I use a `Ref<number>` property of an object and display the Ref in a template. The Ref's value is changed on the WebSocket open and close events. The problem is, the html doesn't change consistently.

```js
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
class Ws {
  ws; // WebSocket
  wsState; // Ref<number>
  constructor() {
    this.doConnect();
  }
  doConnect() {
    const ws = new WebSocket('wss://ws.ifelse.io/');
    this.ws = ws;
    this.wsState = ref(ws.readyState);
    ws.onopen = () => this.updateWsState();
    ws.onclose = () => this.updateWsState();
    ws.onerror = (e) => console.error(`ws err:`, e);
  }
  updateWsState() {
    // console shows the state changes on button click
    // but html only updates at the first time
    this.wsState.value = this.ws.readyState;
    console.log(`ws state ${this.wsState.value}`);
  }
  toggleConnect() {
    if (
      this.ws.readyState === this.ws.CLOSED ||
      this.ws.readyState === this.ws.CLOSING
    ) {
      this.doConnect();
    } else {
      this.ws.close();
    }
    // this.wsState.value++; // this changes html
  }
}
const ws = new Ws();
const { wsState } = ws; // https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#ref-unwrapping-in-templates
</script>

<template>
  <ul>
    <li>0 CONNECTING</li>
    <li>1 OPEN</li>
    <li>2 CLOSING</li>
    <li>3 CLOSED</li>
  </ul>
  <p>ws state: {{ wsState }}</p>
  <button @click="ws.toggleConnect">toggle connect</button>
</template>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-sjer4y?file=src%2FApp.vue

The console shows the state does change on button click, but the html only updates at the first time. If `this.wsState.value++` is used as the body of Ws.toggleConnect(), html changes every time the button is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is because Vue's reactivity system can have trouble tracking changes in certain situations, such as when directly modifying an object's properties. To ensure consistent updates, we can use a ref to wrap the WebSocket object itself, and then access the readyState from within a computed property.

What I have modified in your code is the following:

1. We use computed to create a reactive property wsState that reads the value of ws.wsState.value. This ensures that Vue will properly track changes to wsState.
2. We initialize wsState with WebSocket.CONNECTING, so it has a value from the start.

```
<script setup>
import { ref, computed } from 'vue';

class Ws {
  ws; // WebSocket
  wsState = ref(WebSocket.CONNECTING); // Initialize with CONNECTING state

  constructor() {
    this.doConnect();
  }

  doConnect() {
    const ws = new WebSocket('wss://ws.ifelse.io/');
    this.ws = ws;
    
    ws.onopen = () => this.updateWsState();
    ws.onclose = () => this.updateWsState();
    ws.onerror = (e) => console.error(`ws err:`, e);
  }

  updateWsState() {
    this.wsState.value = this.ws.readyState;
    console.log(`ws state ${this.wsState.value}`);
  }

  toggleConnect() {
    if (this.ws.readyState === WebSocket.CLOSED || this.ws.readyState === WebSocket.CLOSING) {
      this.doConnect();
    } else {
      this.ws.close();
    }
  }
}

const ws = new Ws();
const wsState = computed(() => ws.wsState.value);
</script>

<template>
  <ul>
    <li>0 CONNECTING</li>
    <li>1 OPEN</li>
    <li>2 CLOSING</li>
    <li>3 CLOSED</li>
  </ul>
  <p>ws state: {{ wsState }}</p>
  <button @click="ws.toggleConnect">toggle connect</button>
</template>
```

If you have any further issues or questions, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks, this code works. But I prefer keeping wsState a property of ws. From my testing, the computed line is not needed, initializing wsState inline instead of in the constructor is enough to make it reactive

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Julian Buxton for the improvement. I find the problem of my code is `this.wsState = ref(ws.readyState);` in `doConnect()`. `wsState` gets binded to a different ref every time doConnect() is called. It should be binded only once in the constructor.

That line `this.wsState = ref(ws.readyState);` should be moved to the constructor:

```
// ...
class Ws{
  // ...
  constructor() {
    this.doConnect();
    this.wsState = ref(ws.readyState);
  }
  doConnect() {
    const ws = new WebSocket('wss://ws.ifelse.io/');
    this.ws = ws;
    ws.onopen = () => this.updateWsState();
    ws.onclose = () => this.updateWsState();
    ws.onerror = (e) => console.error(`ws err:`, e);
  }
  // ...
}
// ...
```